# Keyboard shortcut for "replace" on the dialog box

Tags: keyboard, macos

Every time I need to overwrite files on my macOS Sierra Macbook when saving from a different location, I have to necessarily click on the Replace button. Is there a way to do this via the keyboard? I tried enabling All controls in the keyboard options but I can't seem to get it to work. The button focus shifts when I press Tab but pressing Enter does not do anything.

Comment: Try the space bar

Comment: You have to use Space Bar instead of Enter.

Comment: Thanks. Pressing the space bar instead of the enter key works.

Answer (score 1):

When All controls is enabled, a border is wrapped around the focused button. Press Select to select the focused button. Enter always select the default button in the dialog which may not be the one with focus.